# Conditions in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, conditional-statements

The Requirement is I need to execute POST and GET request where the GET request will fetch some value from POST response and then it will get executed. The problem is initially after running the GET request, we will get 404 response for sure and after some time(10-15 min.) we will get 200 response code.
How should I put up a condition for a get request where if it receives the response as 404 then automatically it should again execute after 10-15 min. to check for 200 response code.

I have tried putting up a timer/flow control action but it is not helping my condition

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter)

1. Add While Controller after the POST request
2. Use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${responseCode}" != "200",)}
   ```

   [image]
3. Put your GET request under the While Controller
4. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) for extracting the status code into `responseCode` JMeter Variable

   [image]
5. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler and configure the necessary delay there:

   [image]